# Is it possible to retrieve a HandlerMethod somewhere between interceptors in spring-graphql

Tags: spring-graphql

What I would like to achieve is getting a HandlerMethod ( a method annotated with `@QueryMapping` or `@MutationMapping`).that resides in a class annotated with `@Controller` .

I can achieve this in SpringBoot(for regular rest calls) by extending HandlerInterceptor and casting the handler to HandlerMethod.
For example:

```java
public class CustomHandlerInterceptor  implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod handlerMethod){
           Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();
           CustomAnnonation controller = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(handlerMethod.getMethod().getDeclaringClass(), CustomAnnonation.class);
           CustomAnnonation method = handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(CustomAnnonation.class);
            ...
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get in from spring-graphql interceptors?

Answer (score 0):

`HandlerInterceptor` are meant for Spring MVC apps, whereas Spring for GraphQL apps can operate on many different transports and integrations. This is not the right contract to use in this case.

You could instead use the `WebGraphQlInterceptor` chain, again for web transports only. But at the transport level there is no knowledge of the details of the GraphQL operation. In GraphQL there are typically many controller methods invoked per request, depending on the number of fields requested and the schema binding - this means a `HandlerInterceptor` would not match as several of them would be called for a single request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve that by implementing `WebGraphQlInterceptor`.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RequestInterceptor implements WebGraphQlInterceptor {

    private final ControllerClass controllerClass;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Mono<WebGraphQlResponse> intercept(WebGraphQlRequest request, @NonNull Chain chain) {
        // your logic here
        controllerClass.someMethod();
        return chain.next(request);
    }
}
```

While your controller class could look something like this.

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ControllerClass {
   
    @QueryMapping
    public SomeObject someMethod() {
        // your logic here
    }
}
```

Although this doesn't look like a good design choice. You may want to have the logic which you want at the interceptor level at some other class and register that as a bean using `@Component` which could enable you to use that logic inside the interceptor.